# Why is my ARM chip/Surface processing WCF calls a lot slower than my i7 laptop, and is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Tags: wcf, performance, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am diagnostic testing my winRT store application, and am noticing considerable performance differences between my Surface RT device and my i7 laptop.

Now - i know there is a big difference in expected performance between an ARM CPU and an i7 - but when my average WCF web call on my i7 takes ~0.2s, and my surface device takes ~1.2s I am forced to start looking at optimization and improvements. If the performance difference between the two was only a few hundred milliseconds then I wouldn't mind so much, but the surface device does feel a little bit clunky - and the only bottleneck seems to be the services!

Does anyone have an explanation, or even some performance improvements tips? I should mention that I am running the services across basicBinding with binary serialization.

Comment: Sounds a lot, how much data are you sending? Have you comparable networks between the laptop and the Surface?

Comment: Running on the same network - the data being sent isnt much, about 20 mid size records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have switched to an OData stream to improve performance.

Asides from being fast, this allows me to select only the data I need from the service - both reducing the bandwidth consumption of my application and the speed of service calls.

Answer (score 0):

WCF is a heavyweight stack, so I wouldn't be surprised if it just performs that much slower on a that much slower CPU. Make sure there is no other CPU load at the same time, start your requests from a background thread and display a progress indicator or try switching to a lighter technology like REST/JSON.

Comment: Have done all you have mentioned. Will JSON perform much better than binary serialisation? Thanks

Comment: That's what people mostly use on mobile devices for a reason. I am actually not an expert in this field, but this is clearly something that you should try if you want to look for performance improvements in web service access.